# What clinical studies demonstrated that CelGro improves tissue in-growth and repair for the rotator cuff tendon injuries?

Tags: tendinopathy, clinical-study, rotator-cuff

I read on https://stockhead.com.au/health/orthocell-wins-patent-for-tech-that-can-grow-you-a-new-body/  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170921030149/https://stockhead.com.au/health/orthocell-wins-patent-for-tech-that-can-grow-you-a-new-body/))

> CelGro has been shown to improve tissue in-growth and repair in clinical studies using the collagen medical device to augment repair of the rotator cuff tendon within the shoulder.

What clinical studies are they referring to?

---

I see nothing on https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=CelGro. I also don't see anything on https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=Orthocell (Orthocell is the firm that develops CelGro).

https://web.archive.org/web/20170921025826/https://static1.squarespace.com/static/55d2ae4ce4b0e20eb51007ce/t/57622ba729687fa7422bc538/1466051497971/Early+Positive+Results+Tendon+and+Celgro+-+%252716.pdf just says:

> the first three patients to receive CelGro showed no complications and demonstrated that the scaffold is safe […].

Comment: +1 HA don't you love fitness studies?  Wow the only link that text matches is their on their "stocks page"    https://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapid=54227224.   Considering it's been around since 2006 any reason the "safety clinical study" consisted of literally 3 people.  I hope I'm missing something...........

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

"Evidence of healing of partial-thickness rotator cuff tears following arthroscopic augmentation with a collagen implant: a 2-year MRI follow-up"

Source - https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27331028

Comment: Thank you, that is a neat study. Where did you see that they evaluated CelGro? I couldn't see a mention of it. It looks  very similar though.

Comment: From the methods section: "The reconstituted collagen scaffolds were made from highly-purified, type I collagen from bovine tendons using proprietary methods (Collagen Matrix, Inc., Oakland, New Jersey). The collagen fibers were processed to create a highly oriented and highly porous (85–90% porosity) collagen scaffold with a DNA content of less than 50 ng/mg. The scaffolds were freeze-dried after processing and rehydrated at the time of surgery22. The rehydrated scaffold dimensions were approximately 15 mm wide, 30 mm long, and 2 mm thick."

Comment: Here's one for Orthocell ...

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4595548/

Comment: thanks, but this study focused on autologous tenocyte stem cell injection and not CelGro.